# Is there a way to "Expire" items in an Azure Search Index?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

In Azure Search is there a mechanism to set an "Expiration Date" on items within the index?  I have a need for items to only be in the search index for a pre-defined period of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not at this time.  For now, you need to send a delete request to delete an item in an index.

We often refer to this capability as Time to Live.  It would be great if you could vote for this feature to help us prioritize it, if you would find it valuable.

http://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/6328648-time-to-live-for-data

Liam

Answer (score 0):

As Liam mentions, there isn't at the moment.

One option might be to add an "Expiry" field with a type of `Edm.DateTimeOffset` into your documents and have all your queries only request documents whose expiry date is greater than the current timestamp.